# Relation between being epic and having a "full" image.

Tags: category-theory

Let $g: A \to B$ be a morphism in an abelian category.

Is it true that $g$ is epic iff $im(g)=B$?

Context:
Given a short sequence in an abelian category
$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ with maps $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ I have two definition of exactness:

1. $Im(0 \to A) = ker(f)$, $Im(f) = ker(g)$ and $Im(g) = Ker(B \to 0)$
2. $f$ is monic, $Im(f) = ker(g)$ and $g$ is epic.

I want to prove that they are equivalent, and I would be glad to receive a suggestion on the step above.

Comment: You should add some thoughts, context etc. because otherwise this trivial question will probably be closed.

Comment: Thanks for adding the context. What have you tried? Have you used the definition of the image?

Comment: The answer to your question is **yes**.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I made some attempts but unfortunately I failed because I feel not to suitable with the "new" definition of image as a kernel of the cokernel. Yes, when we work with less abstract structure (e.g. Rings, Modules,...) I have absolutely any problems because I can use set-theoretic arguments, while now I find difficulties because I can *only* use universal properties and diagram chasing methods that sometimes - at the beginning - can appear a bit too confusing.

Comment: @Berci thank you for the answer!